# Jquery image cropping problem - showing another part of image than selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, image-processing, crop

I've got a problem with this plugin

http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

I think that image describes it all.

[image]
I've got selected whole image, but thumb shows only part of it.
It does appear so bad even on bigger images. my code

```
function preview(img, selection) {
    if (!selection.width || !selection.height)
        return;
    var scaleX = 100 / selection.width;
    var scaleY = 100 / selection.height;

    $('#preview img').css({                          
        width: Math.round(scaleX * 300),             
        height: Math.round(scaleY * 300),
        marginLeft: -Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1),
        marginTop: -Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1)
    });                                              

}

$(function () {
    $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:1', handles: true,
        fadeSpeed: 200, onSelectChange: preview });
});
```

I tried jcrop but it does the same

Comment: I need to see mark  up for "#preview img" to diagnose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your scaling is off for your preview. Both your editing area and your preview appear to be the same size (~100px) but your JavaScript is set up for an editing area that is 300px square and a preview area that is 100px square; this means that your preview comes out 3 times wider than it should be and you end up with a too-large preview that is also clipped.

Comment: that was the problem. Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

Value "100" are width's and height's preview image and value "300" are width's and height's principal image.